# Authenticate Adonis Websocket Connections

Tags: node.js, authentication, websocket, jwt, adonis.js

**Adonis.js Version 4.x**

So problem is I can't add Authorization header in the client-side to use the middleware `Adonis/Middleware/Auth` to authenticate my JWT Token.

So what I did is I made a customer middleware for authorizing the socket connection, I can now get the token I passed. So now how do I check if that token is valid? I haven't seen any good documentation on this part, advanced thanks for the help!

**Client Side**

```
import Ws from '@adonisjs/websocket-client'

const ws = Ws('ws://0.0.0.0:3001', {
      path: 'adonis-ws'
})

const jwtToken = cookie.get('auth._token.local')

ws
   .withJwtToken(jwtToken)
   .connect()
```

**Server Side**

```
// start/socket.js
const Ws = use('Ws')
Ws.channel('order', 'OrderController').middleware(['socketAuth'])
```

```
// start/wsKernel.js
const Ws = use('Ws')

const namedMiddleware = {
  socketAuth: 'App/Middleware/SocketAuthentication'
}

Ws
  .registerGlobal(globalMiddleware)
  .registerNamed(namedMiddleware)
```

```
// app/Middleware/SocketAuthentication.js
class SocketAuthentication {
  async wsHandle ({ request, auth }, next) {
    try {
      const { token } = request.all()
      // Authenticate the error in this part :(
      await next()
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}

module.exports = SocketAuthentication
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i just used jsonwebtoken plugin to verify if the jwt token is valid.

**Here is the middleware:**

```js
'use strict'
const Env = use('Env')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

class SocketAuthentication {
  /**
  * @param {object} ctx
  * @param {Request} ctx.request
  * @param {Function} next
  */
  async wsHandle ({ request, auth }, next) {
    const { token } = request.all()
    const appKey = auth.authenticatorInstance._config.options.secret
    const jwtToken = token.split(' ')[1]
    jwt.verify(jwtToken, appKey)
    await next()
  }
}

module.exports = SocketAuthentication
```